# pandas - apply time and space functions to groupby

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've a DataFrame df like the following:

```
User_ID;Latitude;Longitude;Datetime
222583401;41.4020375;2.1478710;2014-07-06 20:49:20
287280509;41.3671346;2.0793115;2013-01-30 09:25:47
329757763;41.5453577;2.1175164;2012-09-25 08:40:59
189757330;41.5844998;2.5621569;2013-10-01 11:55:20
624921653;41.5931846;2.3030671;2013-07-09 20:12:20
414673119;41.5550136;2.0965829;2014-02-24 20:15:30
414673119;41.5550136;2.0975829;2014-02-24 20:16:30
414673119;41.5550136;2.0985829;2014-02-24 20:17:30
```

It contains information about Users' Space (Latitude and Longitude) and Time (Datetime) locations. All Users show a single space-time position, but the last 414673119, which is traced by three sample movements in time and place. I would like to evaluate a parameter such as the Users "speed". I'd like to use pandas functions applied on the Latitude / Longitude columns, related to the shortest distance between two points with the Euclidean distance. 
Calling Lat1 and Lat2 the different positions in space during the first step movement (the same for Lon and Datetime), I can evaluate:

```
distance_1_2 = math.sqrt((Lat2-Lat1)**2 + (Lon2-Lon1)**2)
time_1_2 = Datetime2 - Datetime1
```

and then:

```
speed_1_2 = distance_1_2/time_1_2
```

So far I sorted and grouped the DataFrame by User_ID to detect multiple (and consecutive) movements:

```
# Track User Movements in Space and Time - Sort Information
track = df.sort(['User_ID','Datetime'])
# MultiIndex --> Index on 'User_ID'
grouped = track.groupby(['User_ID'])
```

Now the problem is to access the group information about space and time, and filter Users with a `speed` parameter higher or lower than a certain value.
Thanks so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got most of the pieces in place. Here are some tweaks which may help.

- To compute differences between adjacent values in a Series, use the `diff` method. So, for example, `Lat2-Lat1` would become `grp['Lat'].diff()`.

  ```
  dist = np.sqrt(grp['Latitude'].diff()**2 + grp['Longitude'].diff()**2)
  ```
- If the `Datetime` column has dtype `datetime64[ns]`, then the difference between two dates, `df['Datetime'].diff()` will be a `timedelta64[ns]`. To divide the distance (float) by a `timedelta64[ns]` you first need to convert the `timedelta64[ns]` to a float. To convert it into the number of seconds, divide by `np.timedelta64(1, 's')`:

  ```
  time = grp['Datetime'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
  ```
- You don't need to sort by `['User_ID','Datetime']`. The `groupby` method works just fine on unsorted data. So skip the sort and just call

  ```
  grouped = df.groupby(['User_ID'], group_keys=False)
  ```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def speed(grp):
    dist = np.sqrt(grp['Latitude'].diff()**2 + grp['Longitude'].diff()**2)
    time = grp['Datetime'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    result = dist/time
    return result

df = pd.read_table('data', sep=';', parse_dates=[3])
grouped = df.groupby(['User_ID'], group_keys=False)
spd = grouped.apply(speed)
mask = spd > 1e-6
print(df.loc[mask])
```

yields

```
     User_ID   Latitude  Longitude            Datetime
6  414673119  41.555014   2.097583 2014-02-24 20:16:30
7  414673119  41.555014   2.098583 2014-02-24 20:17:30
```

Comment: So, in this case, in which unit is the speed measured? The time is in second, but the distance? What if I would like to implement the great circle distance between two points?